# ERROR "Client tried to connect using flexible sync before initial sync is complete"

Tags: swift, mongodb, asynchronous, realm

I'm new to Swift and MongoDB Realm so bear with me. I'm trying to use Realm to sync to an Atlas database but I can't get documents to show up. It keeps saying the same error that it cannot connect using flexible sync before the initial sync is complete. Note that in the following code examples and logs, I changed some things like appid and ip for privacy reasons. This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift
import UIKit
typealias SwiftApp = SwiftUI.App
typealias RealmApp = RealmSwift.App
typealias SwiftList = SwiftUI.List
typealias RealmList = RealmSwift.List
typealias RealmUser = RealmSwift.User
typealias UserSchema = User

func openSyncedRealm(user: RealmUser) async throws -> Realm {    
        var flexSyncConfig = Globals.app.currentUser!.flexibleSyncConfiguration(initialSubscriptions: { subs in
        subs.append(
            QuerySubscription<UserSchema> {
                try! $0._id == ObjectId(string: user.id)
                })
        }, rerunOnOpen: true)
        
        flexSyncConfig.objectTypes = [User.self]
        print("Got to let realm")
        
        let realm = try await Realm(configuration: flexSyncConfig, downloadBeforeOpen: .never)

        print("finished let realm")
        
        // You must add at least one subscription to read and write from a Flexible Sync realm
        return realm
}

func login(userCredentials: Credentials) async {
    do {
        let user = try await Globals.app.login(credentials: userCredentials)
        print("Successfully logged in user: \(user)")
    } catch {
        print("Error logging in: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func registerUser(email: String, password: String, app: RealmApp) async {
    let authInstance: EmailPasswordAuth = EmailPasswordAuth(app: app)
    do {
        try await authInstance.registerUser(email: email, password: password)
        print("Successfully registered user.")
    } catch {
        print("Failed to register: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}



@main
struct Main {
    @MainActor
    static func main() async {
            let dummyuser = UserSchema(
                _id: try! ObjectId(string: Globals.app.currentUser!.id),
                username: "jennierubyjane",
                displayName: "Jennie Kim"
            )
        Globals.app.syncManager.errorHandler = { error,session in
            print("ERROR LOCALIZED DESCRIPTION: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        let email = "jenniekim@gmail.com"
        let password = "BLACKP1NK_in_your_area!"
        await registerUser(email: email, password: password, app: Globals.app)
        await login(userCredentials: Credentials.emailPassword(
            email: email,
            password: password))
        do{
            let realm: Realm = try await openSyncedRealm(user:Globals.app.currentUser!)
            let subscriptions = realm.subscriptions
            print(subscriptions.count)
            subscriptions.update {
                   subscriptions.append(
                      QuerySubscription<UserSchema> {
                          try! $0._id == ObjectId(string: Globals.app.currentUser!.id)
                      })
            } onComplete: { error in
                if let error=error {
                    print("Failed to subscribe: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
            print("subscriptions.update ran")
            print(realm.syncSession!)
            
            do {
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(dummyuser)
                }
                print("REALM CONNECTION STATE: \(String(describing: realm.syncSession?.connectionState))")
                print("Got to write copy")
                print("Wrote copy")
            } catch {
                if error.localizedDescription.contains("existing primary key value") {
                    print("User already exists")
                } else {
                    throw error
                }
            }
            print("realm.write")
        } catch {
            print("Error opening realm: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        MyApp.main()
    }
}

struct MyApp: SwiftApp {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            StartupPage()
        }
    }
}


class Globals {
    static var appConfig: AppConfiguration = AppConfiguration(baseURL: "https://realm.mongodb.com")
    
    static var app: RealmApp = RealmApp(id: "MyAPP-asdfghjkl", configuration: appConfig)
    
}
```

```
import RealmSwift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class User: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId?

    @Persisted var displayName: String = ""

    @Persisted var profilePic: List<Int>

    @Persisted var username: String = ""
    
    convenience init(_id: ObjectId? = nil, username: String, displayName: String) {
        self.init()
        self._id = _id
        self.displayName = displayName
        self.username = username
    }
}
```

This code produces this output:

```
Successfully registered user.
Successfully logged in user: <RLMUser: 0x60000283f5c0>
Got to let realm
2023-07-11 15:39:50.303804+0800 MyApp[16275:219469] Info: Realm sync client ([realm-core-13.15.1])
2023-07-11 15:39:50.304049+0800 MyApp[16275:219469] Info: Platform: iOS Darwin 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Wed Aug 10 14:25:27 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.141.5~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
2023-07-11 15:39:50.388790+0800 MyApp[16275:219522] Info: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Binding '/Users/.../Documents/mongodb-realm/MyApp-asdfghjkl/64ad0745b4aa2cb84f6760b8/flx_sync_default.realm' to ''
2023-07-11 15:39:50.389977+0800 MyApp[16275:219522] Info: Connection[1]: Session[1]: client_reset_config = false, Realm exists = true, client reset = false
2023-07-11 15:39:50.391207+0800 MyApp[16275:219522] Info: Connection[1]: Connecting to 'wss://ws.us-east-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com:443/api/client/v2.0/app/MyApp-asdfghjkl/realm-sync'
finished let realm
1
subscriptions.update ran
<RLMSyncSession: 0x600002813da0> {
    state = 0;
    connectionState = 1;
    realmURL = wss://ws.us-east-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/MyApp-asdfghjkl/realm-sync;
    user = 64ad0745b4aa2cb84f6760b8;
}
REALM CONNECTION STATE: Optional(__C.RLMSyncConnectionState)
Got to write copy
Wrote copy
realm.write
2023-07-11 15:39:50.611646+0800 MyApp[16275:219522] Info: Connected to endpoint '1.1.1.1:111' (from '1.1.1.1:1234')
2023-07-11 15:39:51.558997+0800 MyApp[16275:219522] Info: Connection[1]: Connected to app services with request id: "64ad0747e675f16fea06eade"
2023-07-11 15:39:51.846057+0800 MyApp[16275:219522] Info: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Received: ERROR "Client tried to connect using flexible sync before initial sync is complete" (error_code=229, try_again=true, error_action=Transient)
2023-07-11 15:39:54.072277+0800 MyApp[16275:219522] Info: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Received: ERROR "Client tried to connect using flexible sync before initial sync is complete" (error_code=229, try_again=true, error_action=Transient)
2023-07-11 15:39:58.327243+0800 MyApp[16275:219522] Info: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Received: ERROR "Client tried to connect using flexible sync before initial sync is complete" (error_code=229, try_again=true, error_action=Transient)
2023-07-11 15:40:06.551432+0800 MyApp[16275:219522] Info: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Received: ERROR "Client tried to connect using flexible sync before initial sync is complete" (error_code=229, try_again=true, error_action=Transient)
2023-07-11 15:40:22.774068+0800 MyApp[16275:219522] Info: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Received: ERROR "Client tried to connect using flexible sync before initial sync is complete" (error_code=229, try_again=true, error_action=Transient)
2023-07-11 15:40:52.776975+0800 MyApp[16275:219522] Info: Connection[1]: Disconnected
```

I have turned on developer mode and the UserSchema model is essentially copy and pasted from the MongoDB UI save for the convenience init.

After trials using both new users and old users, I learned some key things:

1. The writes are successful locally and persist through different trials. If I try to write a UserSchema object with an already existing primarykey, then it crashes stating that it can't create objects with same primarykey.
2. However, the crash only happens if I attempt on the same user 3 times instead of twice. Perhaps this has something to do with user registration and how objectIds are created.
3. The subscriptions also persist through trials for each RealmUser and subscriptions.count returns a non-zero number that increments each trial
4. The user is successfully registered and I can see them on the AppServices UI
5. If I use the `writeCopy()` function it outputs something like "Could not write file as not all client changes are integrated in server"

I have read a lot of documentation and this error is called ErrorInitialSyncNotCompleted.

> This error indicates that the client tried to open a session before the initial sync was complete. This may occur when the app has just enabled Sync, and is still in the process of building the Sync history. The client attempts to reconnect until this process is complete. Then, this error resolves and Sync begins working normally.

On a forum I read somewhere it said that this error occurs because the logs are not long enough, hence it completes too fast thus it "connects using flexible sync before initial sync". I don't understand nor want to rely on this solution if that is the reason why it fails. Perhaps something could be done with async functions that would solve this?

This forum https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/client-tried-to-connect-using-flexible-sync-before-initial-sync-is-complete/208025/9 got the same error but in a completely different context and their solution was just copy it over.

As a side note I'm connecting from China so that might cause connectivity issues.